# Local Planner does not plan through inflated costs?

Tags: navigation, costmap, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem with my local planner (base_local_planner).
As you can see on the screenshot, the costmap of the local planner does't take inflated obstacles into account.
But why? Because hitting this inflated area with the side of my robot is possible without having a collision.
Is there some parameter to quickly adjust this behaviour?

Btw: These yellow points in the middle of the grey inflated area are obstacles.

Regards
Max
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102621/local-planner-does-not-plan-through-inflated-costs?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-11-19**:
Hi Max. A) What distro are you running? B) What is the point cloud/color map in the screenshot showing? (specific topic please)

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-11-20**:
That's a point cloud from the base_local_planner: /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-11-21**:
What is the red polygon and what is the green polygon?

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-11-29**:
green polygon is the static footprint, red one is dynamic footprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is ROS package called `costmap_2d`.
The costmap_2d package provides a configurable structure that maintains complete info about all position in the map in the form of a occupancy grid, which helps robot navigate.

Particularly for your problem, there is a parameter called "inflation_radius": default set as 0.55m.
I am using ROS fuerte. In my system this parameter is found at:
`/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/navigation/costmap_2d/cfg/cpp/costmap_2d/` in `Costmap2DConfig.h`

For more info, you should refer to the [costmap_2d wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d).

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-11-20**:
In detail it is the cost_inscribed parameter.